# Swift timezones with winter/summer times

Tags: swift, time, timezone

I am working on a world clock, and i have gotten the times for various countries as so:

```
    let date = NSDate(); 
    var beltz = NSDateFormatter();
    beltz.dateFormat = "HH:mm";
    beltz.timeZone = NSTimeZone(name: "Europe/Brussels")
    let belTzStr = beltz.stringFromDate(date);
    println(belTzStr) //<-- correct time
```

My question is when summer/winter times adjust +- 1 hour, will this adjustment be reflected in the code by NSTimeZone? If not, how do i achieve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Consider this modified code:

```
let cal = NSCalendar.currentCalendar()
cal.timeZone =  NSTimeZone(name: "America/Phoenix")!
let date = cal.dateWithEra(1, year: 2015, month: 12, day: 24, hour: 16, minute: 0, second: 0, nanosecond: 0)!
//date = NSDate();
var beltz = NSDateFormatter();
beltz.dateFormat = "dd MMMM HH:mm zzzz";
beltz.timeZone = NSTimeZone(name: "Europe/Brussels")
let belTzStr = beltz.stringFromDate(date);
print(belTzStr) //<-- correct time
```

I modified your code to add time as Phoenix AZ, which does not use summer time and added some extra formatting, especially the TZ to the printed data.

Now, if you use December (no DST in either region)

`let date = cal.dateWithEra(1, year: 2015, month: 12, day: 24, hour: 16, minute: 0, second: 0, nanosecond: 0)!`,

you get

**25 December 00:00 Central European Standard Time**

and if you use July (DST in EU)

`let date = cal.dateWithEra(1, year: 2015, month: 7, day: 24, hour: 16, minute: 0, second: 0, nanosecond: 0)!`,

you get

**25 July 01:00 Central European Summer Time**

So yes, it adjusts the TZ appropriately.